# Show $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[3]{5}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to show $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[3]{5}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}.$ I want to find the minimal polynomial, but I failed. Let $\alpha=\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[3]{5},$ I can't solve either $\alpha-\sqrt[3]{5}=\sqrt{3}$, and $\alpha-\sqrt{3}=\sqrt[3]{5}$.
Anyone has ideas?

Comment: Finite extension is algebraic...if that's all you want. It'll be a little bit harder to find minimal polynomial though.

Comment: I need to find the minimal polynomial in this case instead using that theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We see $(\alpha - \sqrt 3)^3 = 5$. This gives $$\alpha^3 -3\sqrt 3\alpha^2 + 9\alpha - 3\sqrt 3 = 5.$$ Then $$\alpha^3+9\alpha - 5 = 3\sqrt 3(\alpha^2+1).$$ Squaring both sides gives $$(\alpha^3+9\alpha - 5)^2 = 27(\alpha^2+1)^2.$$ Simplifying will show that $\alpha$ is algebraic with order $\le 6$. I know very little algebra, so I'll leave proving that this is the minimal polynomial to you.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26832/degree-of-sum-of-algebraic-numbers